# Set maya project from an external script

Tags: python, external, maya

I have a python script to open maya file and I want to set the project before opening the file ?

I try to find a file or an environement variable which is defining the current project path but I don't if it exists, do you know how I can do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Maya/files/Interface-overview-Start-Maya-from-the-command-line--htm.html

You have all files describe in the doc. You may be interrested into :

```
-command [mel command]
-proj [dir]
-script [file]
```

Comment: Yes that's what I need, thank you ! I just have this little problem, the maya command is not detected, even with maya in my PATH.

Comment: You may have some conflict variables or windows user settings that enter in conflict. You can patch it by put the full maya path instead of the alias or clean your windows :)

Answer (score 1):

So you have a python script that opens the maya file. The file that *sets* the project is `workspace.mel`

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
cmds.workspace("workspace_directory", openWorkspace=True)
```

the `cmds.workspace()` command is what sets your project. "workspace_directory" is the path to where the `workspace.mel` command lives. You can use `os.walk` with the `topdown=False` flag in conjunction with an `fnmatch` to walk up directories from the desired scene file and search until it finds the `workspace.mel` file, and store that directory to a string. Then pass that into the "workspace_directory" argument I outline above!